# Adding new terms to custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I created categories for attachments with `register_taxonomy` like so :

```
function simple_register_attachments_tax()
{
 register_taxonomy(
    'gallery-category',
    'attachment',
   array(
      'labels' =>  array(
        'name'              => 'Gallery Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Gallery Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Gallery Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'All Gallery Categories',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Gallery Categories',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Gallery Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Gallery Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Gallery Category Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Gallery Category',
      ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'sort' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => false)

    )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'simple_register_attachments_tax', 0);
```

I wanted to add some default categories programmatically with `wp_insert_term` so I tried :

```
function a_new_category()
{
wp_insert_term(
    'New Category',
    'gallery-category',
    array(
      'description'  => 'A new category.',
      'slug'     => 'new'
    )
  );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'a_new_category');
```

I am not seeing anything show up.

Comment: `wp_insert_tem()` [returns a `WP_Error` object if the operation fails](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/#return) - what problems does that error detail? (Also, the first code block appears to be missing a `)`, and the second a `}`)

Comment: Thanks for the response @bosco ..  I was just giving rough idea of how I set up taxonomy but thanks for pointing that out, I will fix here to avoid confusion but that is not the issue and I am not seeing any errors returned (I have debugging enabled)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this error would be thrown (definitely something I should sort out some day, though). To be sure, you could do something like `$ret = wp_insert_term(...); if( is_wp_error( $ret ) trigger_error( $ret->get_error_message() );`

Comment: Oh thank you!  That returned "Invalid taxonomy" which is strange, I have successfully set up those custom category "gallery-category"

Comment: Which hook do you register your taxonomy in? It could be that the registration is occurring after `a_new_category()` is called

Comment: On `init` I updated with my full function (not sure why I didn't do that in the first place!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`after_setup_theme` fires before `init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request), so in this case the code is trying to insert a term into your taxonomy before WordPress is aware that your taxonomy exists!

Generally, I feel like `init` is a better location for both pieces of functionality unless you have a reason to do otherwise. But however you resolve it, if you keep the two in separate functions and use the same action, you might want to give the hook which is used to insert terms a larger priority number just for peace of mind, such that it will most definitively always execute after the taxonomy is registered.

Comment: Thank you for all the help and excellent explanation!